# How to get the right Xpath for the <li> HTML element?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

i should make `Selenium` to click on the element of drop down menu using `Java` and `Inteliji`. I should click on the "`today`" button. I tried to copy the `xpath`, use `cssselector`, i used extensions like `xpath finder` etc, no result. The element is `<li>` type, so i guess the problem is here. Any suggestions how to find the correct  `Xpath`?
P.S. sorry for uploading the image, as a new user, i can't put them exactly in the text.
[Drop down menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PaDV.png)
[`html` code for the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjqQp.png)

Comment: Post the actual code, not a description of what you tried. You should also post the error message/exception you are receiving and post the html as text (you *can* do it, even as a new user. It's just a text, like the rest of your question).

Comment: your Xpath can be some thing like this ...... - './/div[@class="ranges"]//div[contains(@class, "active")]]'

Comment: @krsna thanks, i have tried it, no result

Comment: See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the error is that it is unable to locate the element

Comment: @mariam can you confirm whether element is present in Iframe or not. and also post the code which you are trying and after that you couldn't able to locate the element it would be helpful to guide you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't always get reusable XPath locator for selenium from the browser's tool. It returns an absolute XPath. You need to construct relative XPath for the elements.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) you can learn about XPath and how XPath locators work.

The following locators based on the image you have posted.

**XPath:**

```
WebElement liToday = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'daterangepicker') and contains(@class,'dropdown-menu')]/div[@class='ranges']/ul/li[text()='Today']"));
```

**CSS Selector:**

```
WebElement liToday = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.daterangepicker.dropdown-menu > div.ranges > ul > li"));
```

After locating the element,
this part is for after you have clicked the date box and the dropdown is showing.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(liToday));
liToday.click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Actually i have already solved the situation, but your info helped me a lot

Comment: Good to hear. What was the problem?